# on mouse hover give tooltip only to a particular text field

Tags: html, css, hover

I had a text field where on mouse hover I need to get some kind of tool tip which I created using some css and its fine.But the issue here is I need that only to some particular text fields but not for all.
How can I do this.
Can someone help me here

Please find the jsfiddle ,right now getting tool tip for both textfields..But need only for one.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/CvtLq/203/

Thanks

Thanks for the answers..Im adding some more where Iam getting the issue..

I had another text field where it had date picker.Now because of that css,even the date picker is getting that tooltip.

```
 <div class="col-lg-4">
 <input  class="form-control" type="datetime" date-time auto-close="true" view="date" min-view="date" maxlength="10" format="dd/MM/yyyy"  placeholder="renewal date" required="true">
   </div>
```

Below is the screen shot of that

[image]

How can I prevent this coming because of that css for tooltip

Comment: Add span tag after required input field only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your jsfiddle the tooltip is created by the `<span>...</span>` element. You can remove this `span` to remove this tooltip:

```css
span:before {
            content: "";
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 0 15px 15px 15px;
            border-color:  transparent transparent rgba(0,102,255,.5) transparent;
            height: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: -17px;
            width: 0;
        }

        span {
            background-color: rgba(0,102,255,.15);
            border: 2px solid rgba(0,102,255,.5);
            border-radius: 10px;
            color: #000;
            display: none;
            padding: 10px;
            position: relative;
        }

        input {
            display: block
        }

        input:hover + span {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 10px 0 0 10px
        }
```

```html
<input type="text">
<span>Some Text inside... </span>
<input type="text"><!--dont need on hover for this text field-->
<!--<span>please enter </span>-->
```

Now the tooltip is only for the first input.

Another option - add the `tooltip` class to the input and use this class to control which `input` tags show tooltip using `input.show-tooltip:hover + span`:

```css
span:before {
            content: "";
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 0 15px 15px 15px;
            border-color:  transparent transparent rgba(0,102,255,.5) transparent;
            height: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: -17px;
            width: 0;
        }

        span {
            background-color: rgba(0,102,255,.15);
            border: 2px solid rgba(0,102,255,.5);
            border-radius: 10px;
            color: #000;
            display: none;
            padding: 10px;
            position: relative;
        }

        input {
            display: block
        }

        input.show-tooltip:hover + span {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 10px 0 0 10px
        }
```

```html
<input type="text" class="show-tooltip">
<span>Some Text inside... </span>
<input type="text"><!--dont need on hover for this text field-->
<span>please enter </span>
```

Comment: I need that span for the second text field.with out removing that

Comment: check the the second part of the answer

Comment: thanks @Dekel.I had edited my  question with another issue...Can u have a look and help me plz

Comment: It's better to accept/vote this question and open a new question for the new issue

Comment: If you use the second example in my answer this will not happen

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by just adding a data-attribute like `data-show="tooltip"` in my case, or you can use any class for the same.

Look at the snippet below:

```css
.tooltip-container span:before {
            content: "";
            border-style: solid;
            border-width: 0 15px 15px 15px;
            border-color:  transparent transparent rgba(0,102,255,.5) transparent;
            height: 0;
            position: absolute;
            top: -17px;
            width: 0;
        }

.tooltip-container span {
            background-color: rgba(0,102,255,.15);
            border: 2px solid rgba(0,102,255,.5);
            border-radius: 10px;
            color: #000;
            display: none;
            padding: 10px;
            position: relative;
        }

.tooltip-container input {
            display: block
        }
        
        /* Use a data-attribute or class and apply hover conditions */
.tooltip-container input[data-show="tooltip"]:hover + span {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 10px 0 0 10px
        }
```

```html
<div class="tooltip-container">
  <input type="text" data-show="tooltip">
  <span>Some Text inside... </span>
  <input type="text"><!--dont need on hover for this text field-->
  <span>please enter </span> 
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Saurav..I had edited my question with another issue..Can u have a look and help me

Comment: @HVarma If you use the `data-attribute` or any other class with the textfield, you should not get that problem. Contain all the `<div>`s that has a tooltip under one div with some class. Like: `<div class="tooltip-container">...</div>`. Hope you get it.